# Driving in Poland as a European

Tags: driving-licenses, poland

I plan to go to Poland soon and I might need a rental car.

What are the documents needed to drive in Poland as a European? Is my national driving license enough?

Comment: European is quite broad. Which nationality do you have?

Comment: Do you have a driving licence from an EU country?

Comment: @Dirty-flow It's more important to know which country their driver's license is issued by.  I've rented a car several times in Poland and have had problems using my US driver's license (without an international driver's permit) but no problems using my Dutch driver's license.

Comment: @Romain Picot According to https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/driving-licence/driving-licence-recognition-validity/index_en.htm a valid driving licence issued by an EU country is recognised throughout the EU. You should carry other documents such as proof of insurance, and make sure the car has the required equipment such as a warning triangle https://www.rac.co.uk/drive/travel/country/poland/

Answer (score 3):

You should get a [European Driving license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_driving_licence). In my locale (France), every new license emitted since 2013 is automatically a european license. If you have an old license, simply asking the relevant authorities in charge of license delivering for renewal entitles you for an upgrade to the european format.

If you don't have a license that follows this format, according to [this source](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/driving-licence/driving-licence-recognition-validity/index_en.htm), the acceptation of your license is country dependant.

EDIT: If you want to see the exact list of the countries participating in the EUropean Driving license, I invite you to read the article. According to [this source](https://www.justlanded.com/english/Poland/Poland-Guide/Visas-Permits/Driving-in-Poland), if you don't have such a license, you'll require an [International Driving Permit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit) delivered in your home country.

Comment: -1, Europe is not only EU/EEA

Comment: @Dirty-flow That's why I listed the wikipedia article. The license is explicitely called `European driving license`,  even though it only works inside EU. There is a list of the concerned countries inside the article (Poland is inside the list).

Comment: A better way to answer this question would be to list what Poland accepts and what to do if they don't accept that licence. e.g. an international driving licence permit

Comment: @BritishSam I edited to make that clearer, though the list of european countries concerned by the european license was already listed in the 1st article I linked.

Comment: Your answer looks better now, but still some hints - don't just post a link, but also include the relevant information in your post. And try to refer to official sources (even Wikipedia is full of wrong information).

Comment: Also, the police aren't necessarily the right people to ask for a new driving license: they wouldn't be in the UK, for example.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's country dependant, of course. I mentioned it was for my locale, France, where driving license is delivered by the local police department. Maybe that wasn't clear enough in my answer